# How to exit a webview (android)?

Tags: android, webview

What I am trying to do is that when user click a button in a webview page, it starts a service and exit the webview(in animation way if possible).

Comment: startService(Intent); finish();

Comment: No new activity is started, only the current webview disappear

Comment: finish(); works. It'd be perfect if finish could do something like animation, right!

Comment: Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330675/how-can-i-add-an-animation-to-the-activity-finish/4330695#4330695) for animation

Answer (score 2):

If you have only 1 activity you can simply start the service and then call `finish()` on the activity. However, if you have multiple activities you have to make sure that you close them all (see also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842150/android-multiple-activities-and-ondestroy-question)).

Answer (score 0):

You can exit the webView when a specific link is reached. I believe this solution will work in this case.

```
 WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.e("PAGE_URL", url);
            if(url.equals("your link...")){
                finish();

            }
        }
    };
```